# How to build(compile) ffmpeg.exe for windows 10

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to build FFmppg for the windows environment with limited features.I am not able to find good documentation for building FFmpeg.exe for windows. Suggest me the good documentation for building FFmpeg on windows or tell me step by step procedure to compile

Answer (score 0):

See [ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers). It's a script that simplifies compiling `ffmpeg` for Windows.

Run `./cross_compile_ffmpeg.sh -h` to see all available options to customize the build.